# How to dynamically switch databases in Firebase Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Vuejs, Vuex, Firebase app using Firestore and need to support multiple databases to localize client data storage to their own country. What is the most efficient and concise way to dynamically switch between databases, so that one app/codebase can service all client locations.

**firebase.js**

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";

const firebaseConfig = {
    FIREBASE_CONFIGURATION
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const dbcanada = getFirestore(app, "canada");
const dbunitedstates = getFirestore(app, "unitedstates");

export { dbcanada, dbunitedstates }
```

**program.js**

```
import { dbcanada } from "@/firebase";
import { dbunitedstates } from "@/firebase";
const actions = {

  async loadProgramsCanada() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(dbcanada, "programs"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  },

  async loadProgramsUnitedStates() {
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(dbunitedstates, "programs"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  },

}
```

My example above has 2 vuex actions, one for each region. I wish to condense this to be a single action that dynamically switches database. I thought about storing the db reference in a getter and applying it as a variable to the getDocs method, but Firebase does not permit this and returns an error. I'm keen to see what other approach would be the best way to handle this.

The single action example below, does not work as Firebase does not allow variables to be passed as the db

```
async loadProgramsDynamically() {
    var database = "dbunitedstates";
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(database, "programs"));
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  },
```

Comment: by different database you mean from different collection right?

Comment: "*I thought about storing the db reference in a getter and applying it as a variable to the getDocs method, but Firebase does not permit this and returns an error.*" I see no problem with this if done correctly.  You should edit your question and focus on your implementation of that so we can see what you did wrong. You should also be clear what the error message is.

Comment: I will also say that your last code sample is definitely wrong.  You can't pass a string as the first argument to `collection`.  As you can see from the API docs, [collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.md#collection_1eb4c23) only takes a Firestore instance as the first argument.

Comment: @Rainysidewalks no, I mean a firebase project with multiple databases

Answer (score 0):

By constructing the getDocs parameters correclty, this now works.

```
async loadProgramsDynamic() {
    var col = "programs";
    var db = collection(dbunitedstates, col);
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(db);
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  },
```